# How to create dynamic task sequence with new airflow version

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I am trying to create a sequence of tasks like below using Airflow 2.3+

```
START -> generate_files -> download_file -> STOP
```

But instead I am getting below flow. The code is also given. Please advice.

[image]

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

with DAG('my_dag', start_date=days_ago(1), schedule_interval='@daily', catchup=False) as dag:

    START = BashOperator(task_id="start", bash_command='echo "starting batch pipeline"', do_xcom_push=False)
    STOP = BashOperator(task_id="stop", bash_command='echo "stopping batch pipeline"', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_SKIPPED, do_xcom_push=False)

    @task
    def generate_files():
        return ["file_1", "file_2", "file_3"]

    @task
    def download_file(file):
        print(file)

    START >> download_file.expand(file=generate_files()) >> STOP
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the dag structure from START to generate_files explicitly

```py
    files = generate_files()
    START >> files >> download_file.expand(file=files) >> STOP
```

[image: DAG GRAPH]

Comment: this approach did not work , it gave attribute error: 'task decorator' object has no attribute 'update_relative'

Comment: @SantanuGhosh You need to invoke the function to create the operator instance. This same instance must be used in the dag structure after the START and passed to the mapped download_file task.

Comment: thanks for the reply, however I have found alternate way to achieve that using TaskGroup

Comment: hey, Santanu can share your approach ? that would be a helpful share for the community